# Vulnerabilidade no meu sistema "esqueci a senha"

Tags: php, html, segurança

Criei um sistema pra caso o usuário esqueça a senha, mas tenho duvidas sobre uma coisa... Sistema HTML+PHP

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon-16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon-32.png" sizes="32x32">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> ::RECUPERAR SENHA:: </title>
</head>
<body>
<link href="css/forget.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/knautiluzPassMathFramework.js"></script>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="resetSenha">Insira aqui o seu e-mail:</div>
<form name="botaoy" action="" method="post">
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="password" id="password" value="none"></input>
<br>
<input type="email" required placeholder="E-mail" name="emailReset" id="emailReset" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$">
<br>
<input type="text" required placeholder="USUARIO" name="usernameReset" title="No minimo 3, no máximo 10 letras MAIÚSCULAS" id="usernameReset" pattern="[A-Z]{3,}" maxlength="10"></input>
<br>
<input type="date" required  name="birthdayReset" id="birthdayReset" min="1915-01-01" max="2006-01-01"> 
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeSEBwTAAAAAOD2kcTBvz8401DSvI5RTbtG79xK"></div>
<input onClick="knautiluzPassMathFramework();" type="submit" name="botaoy" id="gologin" value="⟳"/>
<br>
</form>
</body>
<footer></footer>
</html> 
 <?php
if(isset($_POST["botaoy"])) {

if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
    $captcha_data = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
}

if (!$captcha_data) {
echo "<span id=\"captchaError\">Complete o reCAPTCHA</span>";
    return true;
}
$resposta = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=meucodigo&response=".$captcha_data."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if ($resposta.success) {

require ("includes/connection.php");
require ("includes/start-session.php");

$email          = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["emailReset"]); 
$username       = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["usernameReset"]);
$birthday       = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["birthdayReset"]);
$password       = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["password"]); 
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE email='$email'");
$get = $sql->fetch_array();
$db_email    = $get['email'];
$db_username = $get['username'];
$db_birthday = $get['birthday'];

if ($email != $db_email || $username != $db_username || $birthday != $db_birthday) {
echo "<span id=\"msgOne\">Dados incorretos.</span>";
return true;
} else {
$sql = $mysqli->query("UPDATE data SET password = '".md5($password)."'  WHERE email =  '$email'");

$sendEmail = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE email='$emailReset'");
$row = $sendEmail->num_rows;
$get = $sendEmail->fetch_array();
$assunto     = "Sua senha foi alterada!";
$emailz  = $_POST["emailReset"];
$mensagem    = 'Olá! alteramos sua senha temporariamente! Mude ela através do painel de usuário.<br>Sua nova senha é: '.$password.'';


$enviar         = "$mensagem";
require ("includes/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
define('GUSER', 'email@email.com'); 
define('GPWD', 'senha@exemplo');        

function smtpmailer($para, $de, $de_nome, $assunto, $corpo) { 
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->IsSMTP();        
    $mail->SMTPDebug =0;        
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';  
    $mail->Host = 'meuhost';    
    $mail->Port = 0;        
    $mail->Username = GUSER;
    $mail->Password = GPWD;
    $mail->SetFrom($de, $de_nome);
    $mail->Subject = $assunto;
    $mail->Body = $corpo;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->AddAddress($para);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Mensagem enviada!';
        return true;
    }
}


 if (smtpmailer($emailz, 'noreply@knautiluz.com', 'Knautiluz', $assunto, $enviar)) {
echo "<span id=\"msgTwo\">Senha alterada! Verifique seu e-mail com a nova senha.</span>";
 return true;

} else {
if (!empty($error)) echo $error;}}}
}
?>
```

Minha duvida é: a nova senha vai ser gerada através de um javascript ao clicar no botão submit e vai ser armazenada em:

```
<input type="hidden" name="password" id="password"
value="none"></input>
```

No lugar de "none" será inserida uma senha com letras minúsculas, maiúsculas e numeros. Essa senha vai ser pega no PHP `$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["password"]);`

E então é enviada para o e-mail do usuário. Print básico do sistema:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O usuário que quiser resetar a senha terá que inserir o e-mail nome de usuário e data de nascimento. Mesmo assim imaginei que um usuário mal intencionado com essas informações poderia usar um alert ou outro comando pra obter a senha gerada no campo input da senha. É possível? Tem uma forma melhor que o input pra mim armazenar a senha gerada através do js?

Comment: Porque você não gera a senha diretamente no PHP? É mais simples, seguro e evita problemas caso o usuário tenha desabilitado o JS no navegador.

Comment: Isso é um dos problemas que notei.

Comment: Sistema de "esqueci a senha" basicamente é por email. Primeiro, mostre na tela um pedaço do email que receberá o token, que é pro usuário não mandar o token pro lugar errado. Depois, mande um link com um token único, complexo, de duração limitada que permita o próprio usuário fazer uma senha nova.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A vulnerabilidade está além disso.

Não sou nenhum especialista em segurança (para não dizer que não sou especialista em nada, de fato!), mas vou listar alguns erros que notei em uns 3 minutos:

### **INPUT HIDDEN: (*Muitissimo* Alto Risco)**

Se existe um inpu chamado `password`, você permite que o usuário envie qualquer senha.

Em outras palavras, se que quiser redefinir o seu usuário eu simplesmente ponho:

```
<input type="hidden" name="password" id="password" value="123456"></input>
```

Sua data de nascimento pode ser facilmente obtido por engenharia social, ou no seu Facebook, assim como o e-mail. *Não analisei o seu código completo para saber se todos os dados estão sendo verificados.*

Portanto seus dados eu mudo para a senha que quiser, neste caso para 123456.

> Você pode dizer: Mas existe o Javascript, que irá mudar o `value`!

1 - Não. Basta mudar os nomes dos inputs (`name`, `id`), por exemplo. Ou neste caso simplesmente remover o `onClick` que aparentemente ele é responsável por gerar.

2 - Não. Mesmo que crie um Javascript "ultra-protegido", você está deduzindo que a pessoa está usando um navegador que suporta. Ou seja, usar um CURL ou um WebDriver (sem conteúdo dinâmico) irá ignorar o Javascript. Inclusive irá fazer o POST que desejar, sem menor problema!

**Alternativa:**

Gere a senha via PHP, no lado do servidor.

Num cenário ideal, permita que o usuário escolha a senha que quiser e continue lendo esse tópico. =)

### **Enviar senha "crua": (Alto Risco)**

Não envie a senha por e-mail, simples assim.
Se a pessoa cadastrou um e-mail errado agora a "outra pessoa" tem acesso a conta, coisa que poderia ser evitada se não enviasse a senha crua.

Além disso se a rede, do servidor, for monitorada/redirecionada/interceptada, irá expor para um invasor a senha.

**Alternativa:**

Não envie a senha via e-mail.

### Falsa confirmação por e-mail: (Alto Risco)

Se alterasse a senha, como no método número 1, o usuário não precisa confirmar a senha ou a alteração via e-mail. Não há nenhum link para o usuário confirmar a alteração ou alegar está (ou não) ciente da modificação. Portanto NÃO EXISTE CONFIRMAÇÃO DE ALTERAÇÃO DE SENHA!

**Alternativa:**

1 - Envie um link (sem senha) contendo um link para "Clique aqui para confirmar a sua alteração de senha, solicitada em {data} por {IP} usando {NAVEGADOR}". Este e-mail deve expirar em pouco tempo (no máximo 24 horas, mas acredito que deva se tornar inútil em no máximo 1 hora após solicitar). O link não deve conter nenhum traço da senha!

*O ideal é que o link SOMENTE POSSA SER VALIDADO USANDO O MESMO NAVEGADOR E/OU IP! Ou seja, se o usuário usou o Chrome em 1.2.3.4, somente o 1.2.3.4 pode aceitar a alteração. Portanto se alguém tiver acesso ao link de forma indevida não conseguirá mudar o senha, por não está usando o mesmo computador/rede de quem solicitou.*

2 - Envie um SMS (este é pago) ou use o F2A para que o usuário tenha que confirmar a alteração também usando tal recurso. Dessa forma, se o e-mail for invadido não será possível confirmar o acesso. Pois além de confirmar o e-mail (dito no item acima) terá que confirmar o F2A.

### Bloqueio de conta: (Baixa)

No seu sistema atual, se eu quiser lhe "trolar", posso ficar pedindo uma redefinição de senha a todo momento, fazendo com que você nunca saiba qual é a senha. Isso ocorre porque o seu sistema substitui a senha antiga de maneira imediata, isso impede que você faça o login com sua senha antiga.

Supondo que haja um "spam" de redefinição de senha, sua senha seria modificada a todo momento, que no final iria travar/bloquear o acesso a sua conta, por não conseguir saber qual é a sua senha atual.

Como a senha é modificada imediatamente, sem qualquer confirmação, você acaba por criar um grande problema.

**Alternativa:**

Crie uma tabela de senhas alteradas e não "aprovadas" via e-mail, SMS ou F2A. Dessa forma o usuário ainda terá acesso com a senha antiga.

O ideal é que se o usuário solicitar a redefinição e depois entrar com a senha antiga automaticamente anule a alteração, uma vez que ele tem acesso a senha antiga. Isso não seria possível no seu código.

Resumindo: dessa forma o usuário ainda terá acesso usando a senha antiga, até que aceite a redefinição.

Além disso bloqueie se houver muitas solicitações de redefinição por um usuário especifico por zona de IP.

Comment: Caramba, gostei bastante do que você disse. Mas ainda fazer tudo isso pra mim é complicado, sou iniciante em php, js... não faço a menor idéia de como criar esses tokens em php por exemplo, obter a versão do navegador e o ip do usuário. Mas achei tudo muito interessante. Como eu faria pra remover a função onclick que gera o js cliente side? Eu tentei mas o navegador fala que não é possível salvar a alteração no html. Quando eu altero sem salvar e executo a operação ele segue o procedimento salvo do html.

Comment: Supondo que o usuário use um navegador que não suporte js vai dar erro no reCAPTCHA, e como o php não vai validar o reCAPTCHA vai dar erro e abordar o php, impedindo a alteração de senha.

Spam de senhas: HAHAHAHA! Realmente, se alguém que obtenha esses dados quiser trolar e ficar alterando a senha o tempo todo seria complicado! Mas ai seria só eu aumentar a segurança da validação com uma pergunta secreta por exemplo né? +1 pra você! Vou esperar pra ver se mais alguém comenta, ai escolho sua resposta como a melhor!

Comment: Bem, o ReCaptcha tem suporte para NoScript. Isso exibe um token e um formulário para o usuário digitar, portanto suporta sem javascript. Alias, o reCaptcha já é burlado com 'bots humanos' ou realmente 'bots software', existem vários, como o "bypasscaptcha" e o "deathbycaptcha.com". Portanto de fato o reCaptcha não é um problema para executar automação ou ação sem Javascript. Pergunta secreta não acho ideal, porque é mais fácil de perder do que senha. Se colocar perguntas tipo "nome do meio do seu pai", "primeira escola" (...), se responder corretamente (o que não faço) cai no primeiro item.

Comment: Pode desabilitar a "compatibilidade" do Captcha quando não há Javascript, mas de qualquer forma se remover o "onClick" no F12 do navegador, ou monitorar através do console, irá possibilitar escolher a senha que quer ou conseguir a senha gerada. Uma outra possibilidade é o que disse, pode injetar um `.val()` junto ao OnClick para obter a senha que está no campo. Há tem outro porém, que não listei, as datas. Se eu acho que você nasceu entre 1990 até 2000, existem 4017 dias. Portanto posso criar um bot, usando recursos de automação de captcha, não fácil mas não é tão impossível.

Answer (score 0):

Aconselharia você utilizar no formulário apenas solicitação de e-mail e usuário. Quando o usuário submeter o formulário o sistema verifica esse usuário e e-mail no banco de dados criar um base64_encode do e-mail e usuário e ainda criar um novo campo na tabela para armazenar um microtime() e enviar como token para o próprio e-mail do usuário com um link para alterar senha.

A pessoa irá acessar o e-mail terá que clicar nesse link para confirmar que os dados são dele mesmo e então será redirecionado novamente para o seu site para outro formulário em que ele fornecerá o novo password. Então você irá alterar a senha a partir dos dados de microtime(), e-mail e usuário e em seguida apagar o microtime() do campo para que está ação possa ser executada apenas uma vês.

Comment: Acredito que isso seja insuficiente. A primeira pessoa com o mínimo de conhecimento conseguirá ver o "base64_encode" e então fazer um "decode", com isso ele já tem um dos parâmetros necessários, para prever o link. Se enviar apenas o microtime ainda tem o risco, porque pode ser previsível, se eu solicitar MINHA senha agora eu vou receber um microtime(). Logo, basta que eu veja uma diferença média entre o tempo que solicitei, o delay de conexão e o tempo retornado para mim via e-mail. Com isso eu posso solicitar sua senha e ir em tentativa e erro com o microtime, fácil não é, difícil também não

Comment: Não vejo sentido nenhum no que você diz porque você não vai solicitar senha nenhuma, vai ter é que redefinir sua senha. Entenda que o sistema não deve enviar senha e sim redefinir senha. Se o sistema consegue enviar senha significa que a senha não é criptografada no banco.

Comment: Você pode prever o link de redefinição, supostamente enviado ao email.

Comment: "Então você irá alterar a senha a partir dos dados de microtime()", numa primeira tentiva você poderá ver que usa o microtime e depois basta fazer várias tentativas, além disso você já sabe " mais ou menos" qual foi o microtime.

Comment: Você não vai alterar nada apenas com o microtime() e se você apagar o microtime() do campo não tem como editar novamente. Serviria apenas para um token temporário junto com o usuário.  UPDATE usuario set senha = 'nova senha', microtime = ''  WHERE usuario = 'usuario' AND microtime = 'token temporario';  
Pelos seus comentários estou vendo tanta preocupação com segurança que nem está pensando na lógica direito

Comment: Pelo que entendi: o microtime seria usado como token e este seria enviado para o email, correto

Comment: sim, para o e-mail de quem quer alterar a própria senha. você não conseguirá alterar dados de outra pessoa se o token é para seu usuário.

Comment: Então. Uma pessoa mal intencionada poderia "prever" qual seria o token, uma vez que estaria usando o microtime. O token, para mim, deve ser impossível de prever, usando o maior número letras e números "aleatórios" e não tendo vínculo com nenhum nome de usuário, data, email ou nada do tipo. Um exemplo: eu acesso neste momento é peço pra alterar sua senha. Até aí o email seria enviado para o SEU email, eu não teria acesso. Porem, como eu sei que usa o microtime() poderei fazer "várias" (porque é limitado e não é "tão infinito") tentativas para encontrar o link enviado para seu email.

Comment: Não acho que seja fácil, ou rápido. Mas existe como forjar um link, "adivinhar" qual foi o token enviado.

Comment: Não vou mais perder tempo discutindo já que você ainda não entendeu.

Comment: Bem, talvez não esteja conseguindo explicar. Mas acho que outras pessoas acharam o mesmo problema: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527706/is-using-microtime-to-generate-password-reset-tokens-bad-practice